# WooCommerce Cart not showing up

Tags: plugins

I have just installed the WooCommerce plugin on my existing Wordpress theme. I have integrated the plugin using the correct functions as found in the WooCommerce integration guide.

Now the shop index works fine, as does the product page. However, when I click 'add to cart', and then 'view cart', the shopping cart page is completely blank.

I am not sure what this is, as the cart page (generated by the plugin) has the correct WooCommerce shortcode:

```
[woocommerce_cart]
```

I also increased the memory on my server as I read somehwhere this could have been a restriction.

I am not sure what else to do, any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled debug in WordPress config and checked your error logs? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. The page.php in my theme was only calling the header and footer php files. It was not calling the the_content, I added this function and it solved the problem.